# how to set multiple token in MultiAutoCompleteTextview Android

Tags: java, android, textview, multiautocompletetextview

I need to set different adapters for different token (i.e When I type '@' it should call AtmentionedAdapter and When I type '#' it should call hashAdapter and both has to be in same MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Please find the sample Code I have used currently it is working for @ but not for hash

```
multiTextview.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer() {

                @Override
                public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
                    int i = text.length();

                    while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
                        i--;
                    }

                    if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
                        return text;
                    } else {
                        if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                            SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
                            TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(), Object.class, sp, 0);
                            return sp;
                        } else {
                            return text + " ";
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
                    int i = cursor;

                    while ((i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') || (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '#')) {
                        i--;
                    }


                    //Check if token really started with @, else we don't have a valid token
                    if (i < 1 || text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
                        return cursor;
                    }
                    if (i < 1 || text.charAt(i - 1) != '#') {
                        return cursor;
                    }

                    return i;
                }

                @Override
                public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
                    int i = cursor;
                    int len = text.length();

                    while (i < len) {
                        if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                            return i;
                        } else {
                            i++;
                        }
                    }

                    return len;
                }
            });
```

can anyone help me in this please I got stuck on it